# Como funciona a tipagem dinâmica em Python 3.x?

Tags: python, tipagem

sou novo em Python e me veio uma dúvida ao resolver o exercício 1001 do Uri Online(ler A e B, atribuir soma a X e imprimir), ao escrever o seguinte código, recebi a concatenação:

```
a = input()
b = input()

x = a + b

print ("x = ", x)
```

ao trocar trocar input() por int(input()) em cada uma das variáveis, obtive a soma. Pelo que entendi, se eu não declarar nada na input, por padrão o tipo recebido será uma string. Estou acostumado com Java, em que é necessário sempre declarar o tipo da variável. Gostaria que me explicassem como funciona a tipagem em Python.

Comment: em python não é necessário declarar o tipo da variável pois ela e atribuída de forma automática você pode tentar uma conversão de tipo de dados

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em python para declarar uma variável não é necessário declarar seu tipo, apenas o seu valor oque é chamado de tipagem dinâmica, diferente de java ou C, que possuem tipagem estática. Além disso python possui tipagem forte, ou seja, não realiza a conversão automática de tipos durante uma operação, diferente de PHP:

```
    >>> a = 10
    >>> b = "10"
    >>> a + b
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Como se pode observar nesse código ao tentar realizar a operação ela retorna um erro, oque denota a tipagem forte.
No caso do da função *input()* ela sempre retorna uma string, oque acontece é uma conversão de tipo ao colocar *int(input())* você transforma o conteúdo em inteiro, ou seja:

```
    >>> a = int(input())
```

É o mesmo que:

```
    >>> a = input()
    >>> a = int(a)
```