# Equação de segundo grau em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

O código a seguir calcula raízes, vértices e delta de equações de segundo grau.

O código roda limpo a primeira vez, mas quando faço o loop para reiniciá-lo dá um erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 58, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Lembrando que o `a` (coeficiente de x²) tem que ser, terminantemente, diferente de 0!

Código:

```
#Equação de Segundo grau
#CLS
def cls():
    import os
    os.system('cls')
#FUNÇÕES
def delta(a,b,c):
    delta = (b**2) - (4*a*c)
    return {"delta":delta}
def raizes(a,b,c,delta):
    x1 = (-b+ delta**(1.0/2.0)) / (2.0*a)
    x2 = (-b- delta**(1.0/2.0)) / (2.0*a)
    return {"x1":x1,"x2":x2}
def vertices(a,b,delta):
    xv = (-(b))/ (2.0*a)
    yv = (-(delta))/ (4.0*a)
    return {"xv":xv,"yv":yv}
#PERGUNTA
def pergunta(valor):
    try:
        n = int(input("Qual o valor de %s? "%valor))
        return n
    except ValueError:
        n = " "
        return n
#PROGRAMA
valores = ["B","C"]
resposta = []
perguntarNovamente = None
perguntarNovamente2 = True
while True:
    print("Equação de segundo grau - Solução \n(Delta,Raízes e Vértices)")
    print()
    while perguntarNovamente2:
        try:
            a = int(input("Qual o valor de A: "))
            if a == 0:
                perguntarNovamente2 = True
            else:
                perguntarNovamente2 = False
        except ValueError:
            print("'A' Tem que ser um número!")
            continue
    perguntarNovamente2 = True
    for valor in valores:
        perguntarNovamente = True
        while perguntarNovamente:
            res = pergunta(valor)
            if not(isinstance(res, int) or isinstance(res, float)):
                print()
                print("Valor inválido!")
                continue
            else:
                resposta.append(res)
                perguntarNovamente = False
    b, c = resposta[0], resposta[1]
    a = a
    delta = delta(a,b,c)
    raizes = raizes(a,b,c,delta['delta'])
    vertice = vertices(a,b,delta['delta'])
    if delta['delta']<0:
        print()
        print("- Delta: %.2f"%delta['delta'])
        print("- Raízes: Essa função não apresenta uma raiz real!")
        print()
    elif delta['delta']==0:
        print()
        print("- Delta: %.2f"%delta['delta'])
        print("- Raízes: Essa função apresenta uma raiz reais: %.2f"%raizes['x1'])
        print("- X Vértice: %.2f"%vertice['xv'])
        print("- Y Vértice: %.2f"%vertice['yv'])
    else:
        print()
        print("- Delta: %.2f"%delta['delta'])
        print("- Raízes: Essa função apresenta duas raízes reais: %.2f e %.2f"%(raizes['x1'], raizes['x2']))
        print("- X Vértice: %.2f"%vertice['xv'])
        print("- Y Vértice: %.2f"%vertice['yv'])

    while True:
        an = input("Deseja reiniciar? (s/n) ")
        while an not in("s","n"):
            continue
        cls()
        break
    if an == "s":
        continue
    else:
        print("Muito Obrigado")
        break
```

Link do código: https://repl.it/D2b9/3

Comment: Evite de colocar o código externamente, a não ser como uma coisa extra.

Comment: Você comentou que dá um erro quando vc faz o loop, mas que erro? Complemente sua questão. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Há conflitos entre variáveis e nomes de funções.

Você tem as funções `delta` e `raizes`:

```
def delta(a,b,c):
    delta = (b**2) - (4*a*c)
    return {"delta":delta}

def raizes(a,b,c,delta):
    x1 = (-b+ delta**(1.0/2.0)) / (2.0*a)
    x2 = (-b- delta**(1.0/2.0)) / (2.0*a)
    return {"x1":x1,"x2":x2}
```

No `While` é invocado ambas as funções:

```
while True:
    print("Equação de segundo grau - Solução \n(Delta,Raízes e Vértices)")
    # ....

    delta = delta(a,b,c)
    raizes = raizes(a,b,c,delta['delta'])
```

Ao atribuir o resultado das funções `delta` e `raizes` para as variáveis de mesmo nome, as funções não serão mais referenciadas, antes do *loop*, `delta` e `raizes` são funções, no *loop* a partir da primeira iteração, são variáveis que guardam os resultados das funções.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
def foo():
    print ("foo")

foo()       # foo
foo = "bar" 
print (foo) # bar
```

O fato de `foo` originalmente ser uma função não tem qualquer influência sobre quais tipos de dados podem ser atribuídos a ele no futuro. Isso é a [tipagem dinâmica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_tipos).

Para resolver o problema, renomeie as variáveis `delta` e `raizes` para outra coisa, por exemplo, `d` e `r` ou use outros nomes para as funções.

Veja também:

1. [**Como funciona a tipagem dinâmica em Python 3.x?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135924/6454)
2. [**Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem de programação estática e dinâmica?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/6454)
3. [**Why is Python a dynamic language and also a strongly typed language**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language)

Comment: Muito Obrigado Amigo! estou começando agora no python :)

Answer (score -1):

```
print('equação do 2° gral')
print('x²-x+1=0, a = x², b = x, c = 1')
a = int(input('De valor à a'))
b = int(input('De valor à b'))
c = int(input('De valor à c'))
print('A formula é (b*b - 4*a*c)')
delta= b*b-4*a*c
print('delta é {}'.format(delta))
print('Ainda não acabamos')
x = (-b - (delta)**(1/2)/(2*a)
x1 = (-b + (delta)**(1/2)/(2*a)
print('x1 = {}, x2 = {}'.format(x1, x))
```

Comment: Você poderia trazer juntamente ao seu código uma breve explicação do que ele faz?